# Getting a ScriptCompactor Error, failing to inline import a file

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dart-pub

The application I was working on used to work find, I did a pub upgrade, it broke, so i was in the process of reverting.  I wiped the cache, I reverted the application, and did a pub get.

I noticed that this error has popped up and has failed to get resolved.

```
[Error from ScriptCompactor on seg_ui|web/index.html]:
line 7, column 3 of web\index.html: Failed to inline HTML import: Could not find asset polymer_elements|lib/iron_flex_layout/classes/iron_flex_layout.html.
null
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout/classes/iron_flex_layout.html">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Build completed with 1 errors.
[web] GET index.html => Could not find asset seg_ui|web/index.html.
```

I was looking in the file it is referencing, index.html, and saw the line as expected.  I tried to comment it out but that didnt work.  I removed it to see what would happen and it seems that I get a bunch of warning sabout a bunch of other polymer assets not being found.

Examples:

```
[web] GET packages/polymer_elements/iron_resizable_behavior.dart => Could not find asset polymer_elements|lib/iron_resizable_behavior.dart.
```

and

```
[Warning from ImportInliner on seg_ui|web/index.html]:
line 10, column 1 of lib\components\dialog\dialog.html: Failed to inline HTML import: Could not find asset polymer_elements|lib/neon_animation/animations/slide_from_right_animation.html.
null
<link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/polymer_elements/neon_animation/animations/slide_from_right_animation.html">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can someone explain why this is occurring and the steps to resolve it?  It seems that for some reason, all of my assets are not being correctly understood.

As a side note:  When i go to my pubspec, and go get everything is up to date.  If i try to repair, it will seem to repair with the exception of a few files having a `HandshakeException: Connection terminated during Handshake.`

Comment: Did you try deleting the `.pub` directory in your project directory?

Comment: i actually thought that was a reference to AppData pub.  give me a second, ill check

Comment: `.pub` and `pub-cache` are two different things. You need to run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` again after you purged `.pub`.

Comment: bingo! Deleted `.pub`, did `pub get`, and then opened in browser and it is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `pub upgrade` breaks the app it is often caused by an invalid cache in the `.pub` sub-directory of your project.

It is safe to delete this folder. Just run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` again afterwards.